# Was Castrodinium named after Fidel Castro?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos

In Star Trek TOS episode Balance of Terror, Mr. Spock says that Castrodinium is "the hardest substance known to our science." Could it be that it was named after Fidel Castro?

Comment: Interestingly the Star Trek author Peter David also calls it castrodinium; "It would sever castrodinium at the molecular level. An anti-proton beam, at full strength, would not be slowed by our shields at all.” - Star Trek : Vendetta, Pg. 173

Comment: The reference in Balance of Terror is about Rodinium, I'm sure of it now. But you are right, there is a reference about "castrodinium" in Vendetta. I just looked it up. It's perhaps a typo? Vendetta was of course a later work, a Next Generation tie-in novel. It's interesting how things evolve sometimes.

Comment: It's a typo that can be found in **all of his books**. I'm wondering if it's some sort of in-joke.

Comment: Actually, Spock called it CASTRATINIUM. It was called "castrate"-"inium" because the radiation it emits caused its original founder's testicles to fall off.

Comment: Castra? Female version of Castro? Fidelina Castratinium?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The actual quote is shown below. As you can see, it's not one word ('castrodinium'), it's actually two words ('cast [rodinium](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Rodinium)'), referring to the fictional transuranic element rodinium.

The '*casting*' process presumably refers to the method used to make the element into a usable shape.

> **SPOCK:** *From the outpost's protective shield.* **Cast rodinium.**
> *This is
> the hardest substance known to our science.*
>
> (He crushes it with his
> hand)

---

The [Starfleet Medical Reference Manual](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Fleet_Medical_Reference_Manual) offers the following information about the substance but no particular indication of why the name was chosen:

[image]

**If I had to make a complete guess, I'd say that Roddenberry had decided to name an element after himself.**

Comment: Silly me! :) No wonder I got so few Google search results. To think that Castro was hard as Rodinium... Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: Your Roddenberry naming hypothesis sounds plausible.

Comment: @sammyg - I'm not very happy with it. It's too speculative for my tastes. I'm going to sleep on it and decide whether to remove it.

Comment: Richard - I have suggested some other possible sources for Rodinium.

Answer (score -3):

Even if cast Rodinium was Castrodinium, Cuban dictator (in)Fidel castro was hardly the first or last person to use that surname.

For example, Wikipedia has a long list of persons named Castro:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Castro_(surname)

And of course Rodinium could have been named after someone with the surname Rhodes

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhodes_(surname)

or Roddy

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roddy

I can add rebel general Phillip Roddy to that list

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhodes_(surname)

or Rodney:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodney

Or other surnames starting with Rhod or Rod.

There is the surname Rodin, - famed French Sculptor Auguste Rodin 1840-1917.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auguste_Rodin

And Roden

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roden

And famous science fiction character Perry Rhodan

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perry_Rhodan

And Japanese movie monster Rodan

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rodan

Comment: Is there any special reason to assume that the cast/crew of Star Trek would want to honour any of the people listed in your links?

Comment: Richard - the people in my links are evidence of the fregency of famous people with those surnames. In the future famous people with those surnames and other surnames starting with Rhod or Rod might occur approximately as often and one of them might have been honored by having Rodinium named after him.

Comment: Richard - I added more surnames to my list 05/10/15.

Comment: Again, is there **any** reason to think that why the cast/crew would wish to honour any of these people? If not, you're just flogging the same dead horse.

Comment: Castrodinium was named after Fidel Castro and you know it! ;)