# From which material are Starfleet ship dedication plaques made?

Tags: star-trek

Are there any in-universe or out-of-universe descriptions of the material that the dedication plaques are made from?

I don't see anything specific on [Memory Alpha](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Dedication_plaque) or [Memory Beta](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Dedication_plaque). They look like brass or bronze, but I'm not a metals expert.

Comment: Brass, I'd assume. I'll see if I can find a source though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you're happy with Extended Universe sources...

We have confirmation in [Strange New World 10 - Second Prize](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Strange_New_Worlds_10) that the dedication plaque of the USS McAuliffe is made out of **brass**.

> *She ran her fingers across the raised letters of the **brass dedication
>   plaque** adorning the wall. Jillian liked the U.S.S. McAuliffe, though
>   the air temperature was a bit chilly for her taste.*

And in [Star Trek: The Captain's Table - Darkness](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Darkness) we learn that the dedication plaque of the USS Stargazer is **bronze**.

> *Even in the twenty-fourth century, some people acted on the basis of superstition. Jovinelly’s compelled her to touch the **bronze dedication plaque** that hung near the turbolift on the Stargazer’s bridge.
>
>   As a shuttle specialist working under Lieutenant Chang, she didn’t get up there very often. But when she did, she ran her fingertips over the plaque before she went about her business.
>
>   To bring light into the darkness. Those were the words inscribed there, the burden with which ship and crew were charged.*

Comment: I accept the extended universe for something like this.  I also found out that there isn't all that much difference between brass and bronze.  Thank you very much!

Comment: @SteveED - In reality they're almost certainly foam sprayed with gold paint and a little black mist.

Comment: @Valorum Partly for weight.  The wall it's attached to is but a prop, and having a real bronze one fall on an actor's foot would be bad.

Comment: @Harper - It's quite likely to fall off since the wall isn't made of [cast rodinium](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/64109/20774), it's made of plywood and spackle.

Comment: LOL! Thank you @Valorum